# How to use action from another web application object

Tags: blueprism

I'm using Blueprism and I have to create a robot for a web application. So far I've had all of my subpages spied in one object, but now I must split that object into 5 different objects, each object for one subpage for example : 
Now I got this : Web App - Object and I must split it into
Web App - Login Page
Web App - Main Page
Web App - Settings Page etc.

Everything worked when I had just one object but now it's not.
I spied elements again for my new objects in my application modeler. 
Also I tried the "Sharable option" and of course published all of my pages.

For example my Web App - Main Page action cannot be used by my Settings Page. I can choose it from the list but then I get this error :

Internal : Failed To perform Step 1 In Navigate Stage 'Click' on page 'click' - Not Connected

What should I do and what should I write in application modeler when I'm asked for the URL of my start page? I've tried the main url for example web.com, my subpages url : web.com/main and also I tried to leave it blank.

Please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

When splitting your functionality across multiple objects, it's important to note how Blue Prism handles connections ("attachments") to individual applications.

When a Business Object is leveraged to Launch a business application, the attachment to the application itself is (normally) handled in the background by Blue Prism. When another business object is created, the attachment isn't handed off to the secondary object(s). This is clearly laid out in the [Blue Prism Object Design Guide document](https://portal.blueprism.com/system/files/2018-02/Object%20Design%20Guide.pdf), section "4.2.4. Attaching":

> An object must be attached to the application before it can be used
>   to automate it. When an object launches an application, it is
>   automatically attached to that application. Therefore, the ‘Basic
>   Actions’ object does not require an ‘Attach’ action. The remaining
>   objects that wish to work with an application that is already launch
>   must first attach to the application.

The solution to this object design paradigm is to include a non-published "Attach" function in each of the secondary objects that's called at the start of each of the secondary object's actions. From the aforementioned guide:

> If an object attempts to attach to an application when it is already
>   attached, an error will result. Therefore, when building an ‘Attach’
>   action, it is best practice to first detect if the object is already
>   attached to the application. A typical ‘Attach’ action may look like
>   this
>   
>   [image: Typical Attach flow]
>   By using the approach above, every other action within the object can call the ‘Attach’ page as is its first stage to
>   ensure the action is ready to work with the application e.g.
>
> [image: Typical implementation of Attach page reference]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it but then it is not possible to attach. 
Also I need to provide in application modeler an URL for the rest of the objects and which URL should it be? the main object contains the main url for example web.com, so the login object should containg web.com/login and the settings object web.com/settings?

Comment: "*it is not possible to attach*" is an extremely vague statement and probably warrants its own question. Ensure you've utilized the correct attachment parameters and attempt the attachment again when the business application has already been opened. You should be leveraging a shared application modeler in this instance; however the URL is not required as part of the Application Modeler setup. It has no material effect except when using a "Launch" action with no parameters, or the "Launch" button in the debugging interface.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already launched the application then no need to keep url to rest of the Objects , just in application modeler u check the checkbox for application is already running, after that in each and every page attach the application and in the attach page keep the web page(all the navigating pages) names in the collection and passing it as a webtitle parameter to the attach stage

This works fine.